# Moving a parent object by a child object VR Oculus Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, position, virtual-reality, oculusquest

I am trying to move an object by moving a handle contained in the same prefab.

the below code seems to be working except the board keeps jumping to a location behind me and then back, seemingly every frame. This is the closest I have got to it working correctly any advice would
be helpful

```cs
using Oculus.Interaction;
using Oculus.Interaction.HandGrab;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;

public class MoveBoardWithHandle : MonoBehaviour
{
    private HandGrabInteractable interactor;
    private Rigidbody board;
    private Rigidbody handle;
    Quaternion initRoataion;

    void Start()
    {
        interactor = GetComponent<HandGrabInteractable>();
        var rigidBodies = GetComponentsInParent<Rigidbody>();
        handle = rigidBodies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == "Handle");
        board = rigidBodies.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == "ChessBoard");
        initRoataion = handle.rotation;
    }

    bool reSetHandleRotation = false;
    
    void Update()
    {

        // if (board == null) Debug.Log($"{nameof(board)} is null");
        // if (interactor == null) Debug.Log($"{nameof(interactor)} is null");
        // if (handle == null) Debug.Log($"{nameof(handle)} is null");

        if(interactor.State == InteractableState.Select)
        {
            Vector3 boardOffset = board.transform.position - handle.transform.position;
            board.transform.position = handle.transform.position -= boardOffset;
            reSetHandleRotation = true;
        }
        else
        {
            if(reSetHandleRotation)
            {
                handle.transform.rotation = initRoataion;
                reSetHandleRotation = false;
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```

[Parent inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53zUh.png)

[Child inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipvHD.png)

Comment: You can't do such a thing with parent-child pair. Look, you change parent position, based on child position. After this engine changes child position, based on parent position, so you again change parent one. And this is infinite loop of position changes. Thats why your objects jump every frame.

Comment: I'd do the following: make only the handle interactive, but still directly move the parent .. in general nesting Rigidbodies is not a good approach

Comment: @Nikolai I have removed the handle from the prefab and added it back as another object. The board is still jumping around in the same way.  The logic in the update function has remained the same.